# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: context

Tags: asp.net, wcf, enumeration

I have a WCF webservice which I am struggling to get to successfully run using netTcpBinding.

The error I am receiving is

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: context
```

Amongst the first search results that I received regarding this error message was the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120297/request-error-with-wcf-data-services) that suggests that this error occurs because WCF doesn't support enumerations (which my service does contain).

However having spent some time in creating another test WCF service I have been able to successfully serve responses that contained enumerations through my webservice which seems to contradict what that post is saying.

Here is how my service definition looks.

```
  <service name="Implementations.CourseService" behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior">
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <endpoint address="/CourseService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Contracts.ICourseService" />
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="Contracts.ICourseService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>

    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:808/CourseService.svc" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>

 <serviceBehaviors>
   <behavior name="metadataBehavior" >
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
   </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>

 <netTcpBinding >
    <binding name="tcpBinding" />
 </netTcpBinding>
```

and this is the end result of invoking this service.

[image]

Any help would be immensely appreciated. I will also regularly check this post so if anyone needs any further information that I may not have provided please do ask, as I'm not really sure what's pertinent and what's not.

Comment: From personal experience ... is the net tcp windows service running/started?

Comment: Running and started, have tried to restart it multiple times.

Comment: ... and it works fine via HTTP?

Comment: Sorry I should have included that, yes it works fine via HTTP. The problem only seems to affect net.tcp

Comment: It's been over a year since I made a WCF service over net tcp. Why is the address empty? Does it take the base address? Have you tried debugging the traffic with something like Wire Shark?

Comment: Can you try adding server side traces and see if there is any useful information. Refer this for setting up tracing : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx